# How to solve: $x^22^{x+1} + 2^{|x-3|+2} = x^22^{|x-3|+4} + 2^{x-1}$

Tags: logarithms

Any help would be appreciated. :)
I tried splitting the equation about $x=3$, but the terms $x^2$ and $2^x$ Together in the equation(s) are troubling me. 
I don't know why I'm unable to apply the property $log_ax=\frac1{log_xa}$

Comment: +1 Thanks SDiv, but is it correct to say that there exist no roots<3? (Which we would get, if there are, after solving for $x<3$?

Comment: Beside $x=3$, there are two roots to the equation. They are close to $\pm \frac{1}{2}$. Just find them following Georg's answer. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT

I would say

$x^2 2^{x+1} + 2^{|x-3|+2} = x^2 2^{|x-3|+4} + 2^{x-1}$   |*2

$4x^2 2^{x} + 2^{|x-3|+3} = 4x^2 2^{|x-3|+3} + 2^{x}$

$4x^2 (2^{x} -2^{|x-3|+3})-(2^{x} -2^{|x-3|+3}) =  0$

$(4x^2 -1) (2^{x} -2^{|x-3|+3}) =  0$

Comment: Thanks for the help, Georg. But how to solve further when $2^x$ and $x^2$ arrive in the equation together?

Comment: Note that you have a product equal to zero so that one or the other or both terms must be zero.

Comment: Another way to do it would have been casewise, case 1 assume $x\geq3$ and case 2 assume $x\leq3$ in order to remove the absolute value sign.

Comment: @HarshalGajjar: As the user sDiv writes.

Comment: If you replace $x$ by $y^2+3$, you arrive to an identity for any value of $y$. Then, just work the case $x \lt 3$ since $x=3$ is a solution.

Comment: Thank you for help Georg and SDiv. :)

Comment: @sdiv can you show me the solution for x<3, please?

Comment: For $x<3$  you have the solution $x=\pm\frac{1}{2}$ from $4x^2-1=0$.